# VLC streaming requires extreme bandwidth

Tags: video-streaming, h.264, vlc, bandwidth, aac

I am streaming a 1080p video from one computer to another using RTP. I use the following command line:

```
.\vlc.exe -Idummy -vvv "test.mp4" --sout "#rtp{mux=ts,dst=10.0.0.5,port=1234}" "vlc://quit"
```

The bit rate of the video track of my source file (H.264 High profile) is below 6 Mbit/s, the audio bit rate is below 100 kbit/s (AAC HE). Nonetheless, VLC uses nearly 1 Gbit/s for streaming:

[image]

Additional transcoding does not really change anything notably, even when a bit rate is specified:

```
.\vlc.exe -Idummy -vvv "test.mp4" --sout "transcode{venc=x264{preset=veryfast},vb=3000}:rtp{mux=ts,dst=10.0.0.5,port=1234}" "vlc://quit"
```

Since some videos work fine (i.e., they stream at a few Mbit/s with barely any CPU load) and others don't (like the one described above), I wanted to ask what possible troubleshooting steps there are. `-vvv` does not give any errors, warnings or debug infos after the initial buffering.

The sending and receiving computer both run Windows 10 64-bit and are connected through a Gigabit Ethernet switch. The connection seems to be fine as it is with any other application. I also tested the VLC streaming setup locally with the receiver being inside a Docker container on the same host, but this made the problem worse, i.e., the consumed bandwidth was even higher and (literally) millions of packets were dropped.

Does anyone have any ideas how to troubleshoot this? I use the latest VLC 2.2.6.

Answer (score 0):

I'd sit on it with Wireshark.

https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChTelRTPAnalysis.html

Comment: Although Wireshark captured more than a million packets within 10 seconds on the receiving computer, no RTP streams are to be found in "Telephony\RTP\RTP Streams". I cannot see a single RTP packet after capturing, only UDP packets, the payload of which is always similar and mostly ff bytes. Is this a VLC bug or am I jumping to conclusions here too quickly? [EDIT: The statistics output says that there are 5 RTCP packets in there, in case this makes any difference]

Comment: What's commonly referred to as RTP consists of RTP, RTSP and RTCP. RTSP (TCP) sets up the payload RTP (UDP) and RTCP controls it.

Comment: I know, but that there aren't any RTP packets.

Comment: Update: It works with the latest VLC 3 nightly. Seems to have been a bug then. If only I tried this earlier :). Thanks for pointing me towards an analysis of the network traffic - seeing it being off made me question whether VLC was actually sending meaningful data.

Comment: If you don't see any RTP - may be something is blocking UDP causing re-transmissions.

Comment: I turned all firewalls off. The switch between the two computers is only a layer 2 switch. But your hint lead me to trying a VLC nightly which seems to work (see comment above). Thank you.